Dropdowns stop working using Livewire and wire:navigate
I'm using Livewire components integrated with the botstrap 5.3 navbar.
Everything works fine but, when I add wire:navigate to the links in the navbar, all interactive elements stop working. There are no errors in the console. navbar toggle, dropdowns, everything stops working.
here's the dropdown menu example
<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button</button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{{route('home')}}" wire:navigate>Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{{route('about')}}" wire:navigate>About</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{{route('contacts')}}" wire:navigate>Contacts</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

Anyone to help me please

don't you need the <nav>...</nav> ?

@francisco , can you propose a better version of working codes?

like:
    <a href="/" wire:navigate>Home</a>
    <a href="/about" wire:navigate>About</a>
    <a href="/contacts" wire:navigate>Contacts</a>
</nav>```

@francisco  ... it doesn't work when i click the navlink several times , it disables automatically drop down functionality

check this.

add data-navigate-once to all your javascript on the page
<script data-navigate-once src="{{ url('/') }}/assets/js/app.js"></script>

